# google maps directive resize event throwing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

When I am showing/hiding the google map, it only displays as a small box in the upper left corner.  I have looked at other solutions and they say to put a

```
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
```

function onto my map, so when I display it, the resize event triggers.

When I load my webpage I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined
    at $e (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js:17:1614)
    at new Ye (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js:20:321)
    at Object.S.addListener (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js:17:1332)
    at Object.S.addListenerOnce (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js:19:321)
    at linkFunction (http://localhost:3000/ffprototype.js?30b6906416281b1680ca5206c9cc5612b1a78d83:47:23)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?9db7e8edebe9ba02ab378f03d9a52d49148583ee:8288:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?9db7e8edebe9ba02ab378f03d9a52d49148583ee:7798:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?9db7e8edebe9ba02ab378f03d9a52d49148583ee:7147:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?9db7e8edebe9ba02ab378f03d9a52d49148583ee:7793:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?9db7e8edebe9ba02ab378f03d9a52d49148583ee:7147:13)
```

My Directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('addressBasedGoogleMap', function() {
    var map
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var googleAddress = scope.$eval(attrs.address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': googleAddress}, function (results, status){ 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var mapOptions = { zoom: 16, center:results[0].geometry.location, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions); 
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: results[0].geometry.location,
                       map: map,
                       title: googleAddress
                     });
            }
            else{
                alert(status)
            }
        })
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
    return {
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

and I've also tried moving the event listeners in the link function, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `map` before you define it. The geocoder doesn't happen instantly, so when your `addListenerOnce` fires, `map` isn't defined yet.

You might be able to reorganize this like so:

```
app.directive('addressBasedGoogleMap', function() {
    var map
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var googleAddress = scope.$eval(attrs.address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': googleAddress}, function (results, status){ 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var mapOptions = { zoom: 16, center:results[0].geometry.location, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions); 
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   map: map,
                   title: googleAddress
                });
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                });
            } else {
                alert(status)
            }
        })
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
    return {
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

That way, you're setting up the listener once you know that map is properly defined after the geocoder returns.

Comment: I'm at work right now and I haven't tried it right there, but I did try putting it after the geocoder.geocode block (right before linkFunction terminates) and I had the same issue.

Comment: This had no effect... the only frame drawn was the upper top left